# R - pivoting long into wide with using part of the value as name postfix

Tags: r, pivot, tidyr

I have such data frame:

```
tall <- data.frame(X=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), Y=c(1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2))

  X   Y
1 1 1.1
2 2 2.1
3 3 3.1
4 4 1.2
5 5 2.2
6 6 3.2
```

And I want to have this one:

```
wide <- data.frame(X.1 = c(1,2,3), X.2 = c(4,5,6), Y = c(1,2,3))

  X.1 X.2 Y
1   1   4 1
2   2   5 2
3   3   6 3
```

The initial "Y" variable has two-part values (before and after the "."). What I want is to use the second part of the "Y" value to divide the "X" column into two columns. The first part of the "Y" value should remain in the "Y" variable unchanged. Its like I want to detach a part of "Y" variable and use it as basis for splitting X variable in two.

I tried to use "pivot_wider" with name_prefix or name_patterns, but I got stuck. I am an intermediate R user, so please suggest something not to sophisticated ;)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`separate` `Y` column into two columns and then get data in wide format.

```
library(tidyr)

tall %>%
  separate(Y, c('Y', 'Y2'), sep = '\\.') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Y2, values_from = X, names_prefix = 'X.')

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Y       X.1   X.2
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 1         1     4
#2 2         2     5
#3 3         3     6
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats a bullseye, never though it could be so simple, but I never used "separate" function before

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(tall)[, c('Y', 'Y2') := tstrsplit(Y, split="\\.")],
       Y ~ paste0('X.', Y2), value.var = 'X')
#   Y X.1 X.2
#1: 1   1   4
#2: 2   2   5
#3: 3   3   6
```

Comment: Thank you! Great solution, but I try to keep it all in tidyverse for now. Anyway, good to know that data.table could deal with it so well, it seems worth learning